# Facebook API - Check if a user is suspended or has deactivated his profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Goal: Given a facebook alias or an id, to check which of the following is true:

1. User is suspended by Facebook
2. User has deactivated his profile
3. User profile exists and is neither suspended not deactivated

It is especially important for me to identify whether case 1 (suspension) is true, since case 1 would be an indication that the user is potentially suspicious.

I observed that calling graph.facebook.com/username or graph.facebook.com/id on a known suspended account returns

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: kamran.haider.5494360",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
}
```

while in the case of a known deactivated account, it returns

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

Questions:

1. Is it okay to assume that the above observation always holds? i.e. for any suspended account the call returns "OAuthException" with a code of 803 and for any deactivated account the call returns "GraphMethodException" with code 100 ?
2. In what other cases does calling graph.facebook.com/username or graph.facebook.com/id return these 2 exceptions ?
3. Is there a better way (assuming the above is a valid way) to accomplish the goal (especially of identifying if it is suspended)?

I have looked at both the docs and on the web, but found no mention about this.
Any help would be appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

1. Is it okay to assume that the above observation always holds? i.e. for any suspended account the call returns "OAuthException" with a code of 803 and for any deactivated account the call returns "GraphMethodException" with code 100 ?

   I think you can just check for "OAuthException"- and that would imply that you cannot access this user due to some possible reasons (in the next answer)
2. In what other cases does calling graph.facebook.com/username or graph.facebook.com/id return these 2 exceptions ?

   - User has blocked your app
   - User has disabled all platform apps in their privacy settings, from [here](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications&section=opt_out&view)
   - User has deactivated their account
   - User has deleted their account
3. Is there a better way (assuming the above is a valid way) to accomplish the goal?

   I think `OAuthException`- is enough, since I dont think you want to club the deactivated/suspended and other users. You just want to check if you can access this particular user or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, it is important for me to distinguish between the 3 cases I mentioned since if a user has been suspended, it indicates that he is less trustworthy while deactivated / deleted profiles could also correspond to normal users. So OAuthException by itself is not enough.

Comment: Hmm, but unfortunately there's nothing mentioned regarding this in the Graph API documentation