# Prevent user's from logging in if they are suspended

Tags: passport.js, loopbackjs

I am using loopbackjs with passport and facebook-auth to acquire users. This works well, but I need to prevent users from logging in if they have been suspended. I have no idea how to implement this. Initially I thought of simply moving the entire user record to a different collection, but that causes the obvious problem of not being to stop the user from re-registering themselves...  so how can this be implemented.

Comment: What do you mean by a suspended account? suspended by Facebook you mean? or suspended by your system? If you are trying to detect a Facebook suspension this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183477/facebook-api-check-if-a-user-is-suspended-or-has-deactivated-his-profile says there isn't much info about it.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add another property to your `User` model, which indicates whether or not the corresponding user is allowed to log in (reasons may vary e.g. suspension). Then add some logic to update that flag (e.g. on suspension). And add a small check to your authentication logic which causes a failure if the authenticating user is not allowed to log in.

The advantage of this approach is its simplicity. No need to add a lot of complexity when it is not necessary like moving records or keeping track of users across multiple collections.